# is there any way to load shared library dynamically without using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ld-preload

Im working with C++ application.
I want to load my shared library to be loaded before any shared library loaded to my application.

One way is to use `LD_PRELOAD` in the code. But is it possible to do above scenario without using `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: This would be a better question if you explained what you don't like about `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Not to mention what you expect will happen when the next person in line behind you has the same requirement. Planning on thumb-wrestling to see who gets to be the "first" first-loader?